# Changing tag names in an XML with all attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I have xml output as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
    <shahid id="hyxq68qa41" nazwa="RAPORT BIEZACY" opis="RAPORT BIEZACY">
      <ali pos="2">
        <khan id="tlpyad6dn2" pos="1:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
        <khan id="bu13zh6dnc" pos="2:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="11">KOMISJA NADZORU FINANSOWEGO</khan>
        <khan id="wzj6a46dne" pos="13:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
      </ali>
      <ali pos="4">
        <khan id="3lmobr88c2" pos="1:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
        <khan id="am4kjn88c3" pos="2:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><html>  <head></head>  <body><font face='Times New Roman'>   <p></p>  </font></body></html></khan>
        <khan id="1aij3588c4" pos="3:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><font face='Times New Roman'></font></khan>
        <khan id="6enzqb88c7" pos="4:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="4">Raport biezacy nr</khan>
        <khan id="umdc9y88o3" pos="8:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">66</khan>
        <khan id="11uzg088c9" pos="9:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">/</khan>
        <khan id="ntkz6p88ca" pos="10:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">2012</khan>
        <khan id="80nzo689x3" pos="11:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
        <khan id="purzp388cb" pos="12:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><html> <head>    </head>  <body>  </body></html>
        </ali>
    </shahid>
```

I want to tranform this xml output as given using XSL

```
<table id="hyxq68qa41" nazwa="RAPORT BIEZACY" opis="RAPORT BIEZACY">
  <tr pos="2">
    <td id="tlpyad6dn2" pos="1:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
    <td id="bu13zh6dnc" pos="2:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="11">KOMISJA NADZORU FINANSOWEGO</td>
    <td id="wzj6a46dne" pos="13:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
  </tr>
  <tr pos="4">
    <td id="3lmobr88c2" pos="1:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
    <td id="am4kjn88c3" pos="2:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><html>  <head></head>  <body><span face='Times New Roman'>   <p></p>  </span></body></html></td>
    <td id="1aij3588c4" pos="3:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><span face='Times New Roman'></span></td>
    <td id="6enzqb88c7" pos="4:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="4">Raport biezacy nr</td>
    <td id="umdc9y88o3" pos="8:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">66</td>
    <td id="11uzg088c9" pos="9:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">/</td>
    <td id="ntkz6p88ca" pos="10:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">2012</td>
    <td id="80nzo689x3" pos="11:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
    <td id="purzp388cb" pos="12:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"><html> <head>    </head>  <body>  </body></html>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- Tag 'shahid' is replaced with table tag (both start tag and end tag)
- Tag 'ali' is replaced with tr tag
- Tag 'khan' is replaced with td tag
- Tag 'font' is replaced with span tag
- All attributes of tags should be copied too

I don't know how to write XSl for this.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing tag for the final **khan** element.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which is one of the most common design patterns in XSLT. To start with you use this template, which just copies nodes (including attributes)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You can simply extend this to add templates to transform your elements to have new names as required. For example, to turn **shahid** elements into **table** elements do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="shahid" >
   <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>
```

As well as creating the new element, it adds all the existing attributes, and then continues to process its children.

It is a simple case to do this for your other changes. Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="shahid" >
      <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ali" >
      <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="khan" >
      <td>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="font" >
      <span>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </span>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<table id="hyxq68qa41" nazwa="RAPORT BIEZACY" opis="RAPORT BIEZACY">
   <tr pos="2">
      <td id="tlpyad6dn2" pos="1:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
      <td id="bu13zh6dnc" pos="2:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="11">KOMISJA NADZORU FINANSOWEGO</td>
      <td id="wzj6a46dne" pos="13:2" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
   </tr>
   <tr pos="4">
      <td id="3lmobr88c2" pos="1:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
      <td id="am4kjn88c3" pos="2:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">
         <html>
            <head/>
            <body>
               <span face="Times New Roman">
                  <p/>
               </span>
            </body>
         </html>
      </td>
      <td id="1aij3588c4" pos="3:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">
         <span face="Times New Roman"/>
      </td>
      <td id="6enzqb88c7" pos="4:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":" columnSpan="4">Raport biezacy nr</td>
      <td id="umdc9y88o3" pos="8:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">66</td>
      <td id="11uzg088c9" pos="9:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">/</td>
      <td id="ntkz6p88ca" pos="10:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">2012</td>
      <td id="80nzo689x3" pos="11:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":"/>
      <td id="purzp388cb" pos="12:4" multiplier="" timePeriodEx="" inne=":">
         <html>
            <head/>
            <body/>
         </html>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you but let say if i put the above xml inside another tag then its not working i mean if shahid tag is inside another tag. What to do in that case if there are tags other than shahid ali or khan and i want to ignore them

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question if you like! Ignoring elements is straight forward though. To ignore an element and all its children, do `<xsl:template match="tag" />`. Or if you want to ignore a tag, but keep its children, do `<xsl:template match="tag"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/shahid">
        <table>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="ali">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="khan"/>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="khan">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="font">
    <span>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you but let say if i put the above xml inside another tag then its not working i mean if shahid tag is inside another tag. What to do in that case if there are tags other than shahid ali or khan and i want to ignore them